# How to set the AssociationField choice label when using autocomplete() with EasyAdmin 3.x

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

#### Is it possible to use a property of the associated Entity as the choice label, rather than the associated Entity ID when using the autocomplete method on an AssociationField in an EasyAdmin EntityCrudController?

Example:

I have 3 Entities with the following properties:

```
User
  name

Certification
  name

UserCertification
  User
  Certification
```

I have the following in my UserCertificationCrudController:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            AssociationField::new('user')
                ->autocomplete(),
            AssociationField::new('memberCertification')
                ->autocomplete(),
            'lastRenewed',
            'expiration',
        ];
    }
```

See the following screenshot when creating a new `UserCertification`:
[The autocomplete value is a reference to the respective Entity ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLAyM.png). How would we replace `User#` with  the name property on the user?

Things I have already tried with no success:

- using a ChoiceField and supplying the 'class' and 'choice_label' to the `ChoiceField->setFormTypeOptions()` method, as well as the result of `UserRepository->FindAll()` to the `ChoiceField->setChoices()` method
- supplying the 'class' and 'choice_label' to the `AssociationField->setFormTypeOptions()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you try to mmake the `__toString()` method of the entity ?

Comment: Setting the method on my User and Certification Entities was the solution

Answer (score 0):

AssociationField uses symfony EntityType, as a result it is possible to use [choice_label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) option

Example:

```
->setFormTypeOption('choice_label', function($choice) { 
    return $choice->getName(). '#' . $choice->getId();
})
```